# Best way to detect sql server congestion/slow response

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We're building a server monitor. We would like to keep stats about our SQL Server (among many other servers and hardware) and after, let's say a month, be able to detect at what times during the week our sql servers are slower.

We're facing some timeout issues and would like to detect the best times to run our report generation tools (that do heavy queries). That would be when the servers are not too busy.

Is there a stored procedure we could execute to retrieve those stats? Or monitor it let's say every minute? So we could store the values and get stats from those metrics after a month or two?

Answer (score 2):

As a general starting point I would recommend setting up the **Management Data Warehouse** on your SQL instances.

**About it:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677306.aspx

**Configuring it:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933864.aspx

[image]

Once in place this uses a series of SQL agent jobs that run on your instance acting as sensors for various things including CPU, Memory, I/O and network usage. The collected data then offers point in time reports (example below) to show high level server performance with some drill down capabilities.

[image]

The data collected can be stored on a central SQL instance or local to the collectors.

This is all out of the box stuff so cost affective until you need something more industrial like the SQL Sentry tools.

Comment: Would it work in SQL 2005? What about exporting the data to my own monitor database? Can I retrieve stats using stored procedures? Thanks

Comment: Seems like it's only for SQL 2008+

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson yes first available in SQL 2008.

Comment: :( Any alternatives? I would like to be able to detect this by myself. Maybe using stored procedures that tell me CPU usage, Memory Usage, DISK IO, etc. etc.

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson be careful, your question is very general. I just offered one possible route to take, but really you need to have a look around yourself before posting questions here. There are many different ways to monitor a SQL instance. Maybe try starting with PerfMon at an OS level if your limited to SQL 2005.